# Using Client-side Templates in Sails.js

Tags: jquery, sails.js, jquery-templates, jst

I am new to `Sails.js`

I am trying to use the `assets/templates` feature in sails to render data client side but I cannot seem to find any working example.

I am looking for the native Sails solution, without angular or other frameworks. Just load `.JST` templates from `assets/templates` and populate them using jQuery

> Can anyone reference a working example of using client-side templates in `sails.js?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is really lacking with this one. However, I managed to get the client-side templates working in Sails 0.12.4 with the following steps:

### 1. Prerequisites

By default installation, you should already have a file `views/homepage.ejs` with a section for the templates:

```
...
<!--TEMPLATES-->
<!--TEMPLATES END-->
...
```

Now, by running `$ sails lift`, templates under `assets/templates/` are compiled into a javascript file `jst.js` which is then automatically inserted into `views/homepage.ejs` between the template section comment tags. However, we first need a template!

### 2. EJS Template

Write a template file, say `assets/templates/example.ejs`:

```
<h1><%= message %></h1>
```

There is one problem. By default, Sails compiles only templates ending with `*.html`. This does not make sense because the template file is clearly not HTML and also because the server-side templates under `views/` already have extension `.ejs`. To change that, replace the following lines in `tasks/pipeline.js`:

```
var templateFilesToInject = [
  'templates/**/*.html'
];
```

with

```
var templateFilesToInject = [
  'templates/**/*.ejs'
];
```

This enables our `example.ejs` to be compiled into the `jst.js` as a javascript function.

### 3. Define _

This is not enough. The compiled javascript in `jst.js` depends on [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or alternatively [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). Without `_` in the client's namespace, executing the template function will throw an error.

To import this on the client-side, download your version of choice and place it under `assets/js/dependencies/`. For example the minified Lodash core seems to be sufficient. During next `sails lift`, a new script tag for the file will be automatically inserted into `homepage.ejs`, ultimately putting `_` into the namespace.

### 4. Rendering the template

Run `$ sails lift` and browse to the homepage at [localhost:1337](http://localhost:1337) by default. The `jst.js` has created the template function at `window.JST['assets/templates/example.ejs']`.

To test it in action, open the developer console, and type:

```
> window.JST['assets/templates/example.ejs']({message: 'Hello'})
```

This should return you the string `<h1>Hello</h1>`. This string you now want to insert somewhere into the document. Let us say you store it into a variable `piece`. You could use jQuery `$('#target').html(piece)` or good old `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = piece`. Anyway, as the result, the rendered string is now inserted into the page under #target element.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best explanation I could get

Comment: Hi! Awesome explanation! BTW, have you tried to use localization in templates? I thought it should insert localized strings in templates but it leaves as is like `<%= __('hello') %>`.

Comment: @ArVan Thanks! Unfortunately I haven't but if I did, I would give the localization function "__" into the template function in a similar way as the message itself: `var template = window.JST['assets/templates/example.ejs']` and then `var localizedHtml = template({message: 'Hello', __: myLocalizationFunction})`.

Comment: I followed the above but when I try to run "window.JST['assets/templates/mytemplate.ejs']();" I get an error "window.JST.assets/templates/mytemplate.ejs is not a function". Lodash is defined  (console logging "_" is successful). Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you define ng-app and ng-view in the layout.ejs ? If you define then create a angular app.js in /assets with routing, then this will definitely work. 
If still any issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for a way to do this without angular.